# "error CS0103: the name 'w' does not exist in the current context" in LINQ lambda expression

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

In a school project I have created a to-do list in ASP.Net Core where I use one partial-view to list all items and one partial-view to handle the "add new item" form. Everything is being updated "dynamically" with AJAX like [this](https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/326/using-unobtrusive-ajax-in-razor-pages). Everything works fine as it is in one page.

The website is containing of multiple widgets and one of them is the to-do-list. When trying to add the to-do-list as a widget on a dashboard, we take the existing code and put it in a partial-view and load all widgets in smaller drag & drop boxes.

At the moment it looks great, but there is a problem with the to-do-list, when I call a specific controller action to create a new item.
The problem occurs when the action calls this method:

```
public Task<List> FindList(int id)
{
    return GetAllLists().Where(w => w.WidgetId == id).Include(w => w.Widget).FirstAsync();
}
```

where GetAllLists is:

```
public IQueryable<List> GetAllLists()
{
    return _db.Lists.AsQueryable();
}
```

The content of the partial-view for the widget is:

```
@using Weplanner_core.Models.Database
@model Weplanner_core.Models.Database.List


@if (Model != null)
{
    if (Model.ListItems == null)
    {
        @:<p>list items == null</p>
    }
    else
    {
        <h2>@Model.Title - @Model.ListType</h2>


        <div id="tableDiv">
            <partial name="~/Views/List/_ListItemsTable.cshtml" for="@Model" />
        </div>

        <div id="listItemCreateFrom" class="newListItemDiv">

            @{
                var newListItem = new ListItem();
            }

            <partial name="~/Views/List/_ListItemCreateForm.cshtml" for="@newListItem" />

            @*@await Html.PartialAsync("~/Views/List/_ListItemCreateForm.cshtml", new ListItem())*@

        </div>

        @*<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>*@
        <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>

    }
}
else
{
    @:<p>model is null</p>
}
```

The error looks like this when debugging:
http://prntscr.com/nka673

I have tried to make the LINQ expression with other variables, I have tried to call other DB methods in the Controller action, I have tried loading the _ListItemCreateForm.cshtml partial view as await Html.PartialAsync, I have tried to copy the exact code from the original file in to the partial view. I have tried to put the partial view in another folder, I have tried to put the LINQ method in another file.

When it doesn't work I get the error in browser: http://prntscr.com/nk9zy1

I can't really see what should be the reason for the error. Do anyone have suggestions to how to get the functionality of adding a new item to work?

**EDIT**

The content of the controller action, *ListItemsAjaxCreate*, in ListController:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> ListItemsAjaxCreate(int? id, [Bind("ItemText")] ListItem listItem)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    if (!ModelState.IsValid) return PartialView("_ListItemsTable", await listRepo.FocusedList((int) id));

    var list = await listRepo.FindList((int) id);
    listItem.ListId = (int)id;
    listItem.IsDone = false;
    listItem.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
    listItem.List = list;

    var user = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == GetCurrentUserId());
    if (user != null) listItem.ItemDetails = user.Email;
    try
    {
        listRepo.AddListItem(listItem);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
        throw;
    }
    return PartialView("_ListItemsTable", await listRepo.FocusedList((int)id));
}
```

Comment: Would it work if you switch places of `Where()` and `Include()` ? Like `return GetAllLists().Include(w => w.Widget).Where(w => w.WidgetId == id).FirstAsync();`

Comment: @SergeyKudriavtsev Didn't work: http://prntscr.com/nkai4l
But thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: The screenshot of the error in the browser, shows a 500 internal server error on the `ListItemsAjaxCreate` method. What does that method look like?

Comment: @hiltononline I have edited the post with the method.

Comment: @Jonafan `return GetAllLists().FirstAsync(w=>w.WidgetId == id)` and then you should be able to access Widget using `await listRepo.FindList((int) id).Widget`

Comment: Sooo, the current FindList looks like this now: `return GetAllLists().Include("Widget").Where(w => w.ListId == id).FirstAsync();` and it works perfect. I am a bit busy at the moment, but will update the post with my edits and why I think it works, later today :)
Thank you for your inputs!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**OP HERE**

I changed the method from the repository to:

```
public Task<List> FindList(int id)
{
     return GetAllLists().Include("Widget")
     .Where(w => w.ListId == id)
     .FirstAsync();
}
```

So the difference was by including first, but also by using [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions.include?view=efcore-2.1#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions_Include__1_System_Linq_IQueryable___0__System_String_) include instead.

Also I was not using the correct ID for routing to the correct group, but I figured that out before using the linked **Include**. I don't know why using this version made the difference.

This suggestion was actually made by someone few minutes after I had made the post, but as I wanted to reply, the post was removed.